# How to "flatten" or "merge" the code that is spread across too many methods in Java (using Intellij)?

Tags: intellij-idea, refactoring, automated-refactoring

This may be a very simple question, however, for some reason, I did not find an answer.

To explain what I am trying to do, lets say I have:

```
public String A(){
return B();
}

public String B(){
return "HELLO";
}
```

I would like this to become:

```
public String A(){
return "HELLO";
}
```

I want to avoid doing this manually.

Comment: It's called "inline method" refactoring. Look under "Refactor" menu.

Comment: Thanks, probably that was a reason I couldn't find anything. Will take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place your caret at the function you want to inline and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>.
The Intellij will find the occurrences and propose you a certain solutions listed below in the image.

In your case you want to select the first option in order to remove the `B` function.

[image]

When you have trouble finding a refactoring automation you can place the caret to the piece of code you want to refactor and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> a dialog will pop up with all the possible refactorings. You can refer to the [official documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/refactoring-source-code.html) for more information.